# How can I setup Angular with Truffle?

Tags: truffle, javascript, framework

I've been looking for a way to hook up Angular with Truffle for a demo dApp I'm thinking of building but I'm unsure as to how to setup the development environment that would allow me to work with both frameworks.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me set it up. Cheers!

Edit:

I'd like to bring to everyone's attention that there's now an official TruffleBox for Angular integration:
http://truffleframework.com/boxes/angular-truffle-box

Comment: please if you find the answer write some explaining post :D

Comment: @ArslanSmal Unfortunately doesn't look like people know how to do it....

Comment: mmm nice question

Comment: Please see the newly edited original post. There's now an official Trufflebox for Angular available :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used truffle with react. The process will be similar for angular.

Truffle offers two ways to integrate with other frameworks:

- [`truffle-solidity-loader`](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle-solidity-loader): a webpack plugin which will build and deploy your contracts if needed, then provide you with a deployed truffle-contract contract when `require`d.
- [`truffle-contract`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract): a javascript library which gives you access to the nice contract API. It's the same API used for testing and the truffle console. Here is an example of using it:

  ```
  // any web3 provider
  var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");

  // the truffle-contract package
  var contract = require("truffle-contract");

  // include the file created by truffle build in `build/`
  var myContractDef = require('myContract.json');

  // Create the wrapped contract
  var MyContract = contract(myContractDef);

  // give it web3 powers!
  MyContract.setProvider(provider);

  // use the contract
  MyContract.deployed(instance => // do stuff...
  ```

  All you will need to do is make the built json file accessible to your runtime and wrap it in a `truffle-contract`. This will not automatically build and deploy your contracts when they change. Check out [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/better-pattern-to-detect-web3-default-account-when-using-metamask/17494#17494) to see how to create a provider and get the default account. You'll probably want to use angular's dependency injection by wrapping the contract in a service.

Comment: Please see the newly edited original post. There's now an official Trufflebox for Angular available :)

Answer (score 1):

With Truffle version 4, its quite simple to have the integrate front web packs(Vue,Angular,React)..

Reference : http://truffleframework.com/boxes/

To use angular in your project,its now simple with the below command

> truffle unbox Quintor/angular-truffle-box

Reference :http://truffleframework.com/boxes/angular-truffle-box

**Edit Version 1 : Adding this answer so others know there has been an update with truffle4.**

Comment: I am not able to unbox this box... getting issue with npm install command during unbox...

I have build tools installed for native node module...

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Angular 2/4 with Truffle can be done as follows:

#### 1- Initialize a new Angular project

```
$ ng new myDapp
```

This will setup the most basic Angular folder structure.

---

#### 2- Cd into myDapp and initialize truffle.

```
$ cd myDapp
$ truffle init
```

This will install truffle dependencies and create the truffle config file and contracts/migrations folders.

---

#### 3- Install truffle-contract package to be able to make calls/transactions with truffle.

```
$ npm install truffle-contract --save
```

---

#### 4- Using truffle with Angular

a) Import web3, truffle and contracts you'll be using. (I'm writing this example using the default MetaCoin contract that comes with truffle)

**In app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, HostListener, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const coinArtifacts = require('../../build/contracts/MetaCoin.json');
declare var window: any;
```

It's probable you'll get an error with require. If that happens, in typings.d.ts, add to the end of the file:

```
declare var require: any;
```

b) Back in app.component.ts.

```
export class AppComponent {
  Coin = contract(coinArtifacts);
  coinInstance:any;

  account: any;
  accounts: any;
  web3: any;
}
```

c) Add the following functions to AppComponent

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

  @HostListener('window:load')
  windowLoaded() {
    this.checkAndInstantiateWeb3();
    this.onReady();
  }

  checkAndInstantiateWeb3 = () => {
    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      console.warn(
        'Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don\'t appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you\'ve configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask'
      );
      // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
      this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      console.warn(
        'No web3 detected, falling back to Infura Ropsten'
        //'No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it\'s inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask'
      );
      // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
      this.web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')

      );
    }
  };

  onReady = () => {
    // Bootstrap the MetaCoin abstraction for Use.
    this.Coin.setProvider(this.web3.currentProvider);

    // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
    this.web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accs) => {
      if (err != null) {
        alert('There was an error fetching your accounts.');
        return;
      }

      if (accs.length === 0) {
        alert(
          'You are not connected to an Ethereum client. You can still browse the data, but you will not be able to perform transactions.'
        );
        return;
      }
      this.accounts = accs;
      this.account = this.accounts[0];

      // This is run from window:load and ZoneJS is not aware of it we
      // need to use _ngZone.run() so that the UI updates on promise resolution
      this._ngZone.run(() =>{
        //Initial loading of UI
        //Load balances or whatever
      });

    });

  };
```

That's all you need to get started.

- windowLoaded() method will make sure everything is set up after Metamask is loaded.
- checkAndInstantiateWeb3() initializes web3 object
- onReady() gets the accounts / account connected to the Dapp and makes the contract abstraction available.

Now you can use truffle with Angular. Just make sure testrcp is running and then do:

```
$ truffle compile
$ truffle migrate
$ ng serve
```

Comment: Please see the newly edited original post. There's now an official Trufflebox for Angular available :)

Comment: Except for the inclusion of truffle-contract in package.json it looks quite empty.