# Better pattern to detect web3 default account when using metamask

Tags: web3js, javascript, metamask, web3-providers

Context: I want to use blockies to render an identicon on the page, i get the defaultAccount from web3, for this, the user has to be logged on to metamask with a selected address from his wallet.

The problem: the web app seems to not detect the web3 object on the load event of the page, wchih is the recommended place to detect it.

The code: below is inspired from recommendations at:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1158

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check

I keep having intermittent behaviour, sometimes web3 is there and sometimes it is not, the only solution I can think of is to have a timer, but that seems to me a bit too simplistic, I would prefer something more elegant.

Question: Is there a better solution to detect the defaultAccount from web3 when the page loads?

```
 function startApp() { 
        GenerateIdenticon();  
}  


window.addEventListener('load', function () { 

// Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {

    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
    if (web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask === true) {
        if (typeof web3.eth.defaultAccount === 'undefined') {
            document.body.innerHTML = '<body><h1>Oops! Your browser does not support Ethereum Ðapps.</h1></body>';   
        }
        else {
            startApp();
        }
    }
    else {
         alert('No web3? Please use google chrome and metamask plugin to enter this Dapp!', null, null);
        // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
       window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The one method that is more reliable than the in-page `accounts` array is `web3.eth.getAccounts(accounts => console.log(accounts[0]))`.

This will asynchronously request the accounts array, and call back whenever it's available.

Comment: Thanks a lot DanF, indeed using this method always returns the desirable state.

Comment: Alternative: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(...)`.

Comment: Since I couldn't get this work, I discover that `getAccounts` method returns two (2) arguments and the `accounts` is the second. In other words: `web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => console.log(accounts[0]))`.

Comment: Does that have an risk to flood the provider if it requests that information  each 100 seconds ?

Comment: This is not a severe risk, because the account provider is local, so this is not a network call, just a value check on the same machine.

Comment: chrome console shows "undefined" value

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I use in my Dapp. It seems to work pretty well.

```
function getWeb3(callback) {
  if (typeof window.web3 === 'undefined') {
    // no web3, use fallback
    console.error("Please use a web3 browser");
  } else {
    // window.web3 == web3 most of the time. Don't override the provided,
    // web3, just wrap it in your Web3.
    var myWeb3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider); 

    // the default account doesn't seem to be persisted, copy it to our
    // new instance
    myWeb3.eth.defaultAccount = window.web3.eth.defaultAccount;

    callback(myWeb3);
  }
}
```

Used like so:

```
function startApp(web3) {
  // ...
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  getWeb3(startApp);
});
```

The key difference is that I copy the `defaultAccount` from the original `window.web3` instance. You'll notice that there is no MetaMask specific code [`web3.eth.defaultAccount`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethdefaultaccount) is part of the Javascript API. MetaMask seems to populate `defaultAccount` once you unlock your wallet.

Comment: thanks @0xcaff but as DeviateFish mentioned, you still have the same problem with the defaultAccounts, anyways I think you have a point about not having any code related to metamask and just rely on the standard web3 calls.

Answer (score 6):

Checking `web3.eth.accounts[0]` every 100 milliseconds is **way** faster in some cases than `web3.eth.getAccounts()`:

```
// Option 1:
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);

// Option 2:
(function loop() {
  if (web3.eth.accounts[0]) {
    console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
  } else {
    setTimeout(loop, 100);
  }
}());
```

When using a proxy, `Option 2` was up to 35 seconds (!) faster for me than `Option 1`.

---

Regarding `web3.eth.defaultAccount`, [MetaMask Documentation](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#raising_hand-account-list-reflects-user-preference) says it should not be used to detect what account is currently selected by the user.

---

Btw, according to MetaMask Documentation, you will have to use `setTimeout`/`setInterval` anyway to listen for [selected account changes](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#ear-listening-for-selected-account-changes):

```
var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
setInterval(function () {
  if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
    account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    updateInterface();
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple things I've noticed from using MetaMask.

1. `defaultAccount` isn't always populated.  It's safer to use `web3.eth.accounts[0]` as your check to see whether or not an account is selected.  You'll need to poll this value periodically if you want to know if the selected account changes, as well.
2. The `load` event doesn't always seem reliable in some of my experiences, either.  I eventually resolved this, but I don't have my code on hand to demonstrate how.  I'll update this post with it later, if the `accounts[0]` piece isn't enough.

Comment: thanks @DeviateFish indeed I could not make sure the defaultAccount was populated everytime, but DanF recommended to use getAccounts with a callback function. Also for the change of accounts, it would be nice to have a watch callback whenever the account changes don't you think?

Comment: It indeed would be nice, but such a thing currently doesn't exist in web3 (or via the RPC, as far as I can tell).

Using the async methods are generally preferable, so I'm glad that's working for you!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using React and you are facing this problem, you only need to do this:

**1. Install web3:**

```
npm install web3 --save
```

**2. Check if MetaMask is there:**

```
import 'Web3' from 'web3';

// ...

componentDidMount() {

  // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser (MetaMask).
  // (since 'web3' is global, we need to use 'window')
  if (window.web3 && window.web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask) {
    window.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {

      // Do whatever you need to.
      this.setState({wallet: accounts[0]});
    });
  } else {
    console.log('MetaMask account not detected :(');
  }
}
```

Comment: My currentProvider property returns as null at this point. Is there a callback or something I can use when it completes?

Comment: @user339946 does return `null` when you unlocked Metamask?

Comment: Yeah, metamask is unlocked. It seems that the web3 object isn't ready for the component at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you check for mobile wallets like Trust or Status? I can catch metamask simply but none of the mobile wallets.

Comment: I don't know @JamboDev :(

Answer (score -1):

Not a shameless plug.

Recently started using: https://www.blocknative.com/

They offer good onboarding patterns with MetaMask.